# join query with conditional check in sql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to get some data from multiple tables using join query. I have a reservation table where I store the "pick-up location id" and "drop location id" and another table "location" where the location names were stored.
I'm trying to get the location name (pick-up and drop location) in 2 different variables from the "location" table with these 2 ids from the reservation table.

I have the tables with the following parameters.
Location table: "locations_deatils" has location_name location_id.
Reservation table: reservation_cars has pickup_location id, drop_location id, pick_up date, drop_date

```
SELECT l.location_name as pick-up_loc, 
       l.location_name as drop_loc, 
       c.pickup_date, 
       c.return_date, 
FROM locations_deatils l inner join 
     reservation_cars c on l.locations_id = c.pickup_location and l.locations_id 
= c.return_location 
WHERE c.pickup_date >= :pickupTime and c.return_date <=:returnTime;
```

Comment: And what is your question? Is there anything not working yet? Or do you even receive an error message?

Comment: Provide table structures off all tables involved with `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` Also provide example data as a ascii data table. Or provide a sqlfiddle.com or a db-fiddle.com with the table structures and example data. Also provide expected output as ascii data table.. It's hard to produce a SQL query from reverse engineering a other SQL query and some text without example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a separate join for the pick-up and for the drop location.

```
SELECT l1.location_name as 'pick-up location', l2.location_name as 'drop location', pickup_date, return_date
FROM reservation_cars r
JOIN locations_deatils l1 ON l1.locations_id = r.pickup_location
JOIN locations_deatils l2 ON l2.locations_id = r.return_location
WHERE r.pickup_date >= :pickupTime 
  AND r.drop_date <= :returnTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant something like this:

```
SELECT p_loc.location_name AS pickup_location,
       cars.pickup_date,
       d_loc.location_name AS drop_location,
       cars.return_date
FROM   reservation_cars cars
JOIN   location_details p_loc
  ON   cars.pickup_location = p_loc.location_id
JOIN   location_details d_loc
  ON   cars.return_location = d_loc.location_id
WHERE  .....
```

You might need to use an `outer join` in case the pickup and/or return locations are not set (yet).